# pip3 not installing Jupyter on Windows

Tags: windows, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

This is my first time here. So, sorry in advance for any mistakes I can make.

I installed Python 3.6.1 on my Windows 8. Then I tried to install Jupyter by the pip3 method because Anaconda ALWAYS fails when downloading (I have tried past year a dozen times and today I tried again twice). I follow the [instructions given](http://jupyter.org/install.html) and then this happens:

```
   Microsoft Windows [Versión 6.2.9200]
    (c) 2012 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Myuser>pip3 install --upgrade pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\pyt
hon\python36-32\lib\site-packages

C:\Users\Myuser>pip3 install jupyter
Collecting jupyter
  Downloading jupyter-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting ipywidgets (from jupyter)
  Downloading ipywidgets-6.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (46kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 409kB/s
Collecting qtconsole (from jupyter)
  Downloading qtconsole-4.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (104kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 112kB 936kB/s
Collecting nbconvert (from jupyter)
  Downloading nbconvert-5.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (372kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 378kB 728kB/s
Collecting ipykernel (from jupyter)
  Downloading ipykernel-4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (98kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 1.6MB/s
Collecting jupyter-console (from jupyter)
  Downloading jupyter_console-5.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting notebook (from jupyter)
  Downloading notebook-4.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 6.9MB 93kB/s
Collecting nbformat>=4.2.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading nbformat-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (154kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 163kB 1.2MB/s
Collecting traitlets>=4.3.1 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading traitlets-4.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (74kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 1.5MB/s
Collecting widgetsnbextension~=2.0.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading widgetsnbextension-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.1MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.1MB 457kB/s
Collecting ipython>=4.0.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading ipython-5.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (750kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 757kB 676kB/s
Collecting jupyter-core (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Downloading jupyter_core-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 81kB 1.1MB/s
Collecting pygments (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Downloading Pygments-2.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (841kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 849kB 356kB/s
Collecting jupyter-client>=4.1 (from qtconsole->jupyter)
  Downloading jupyter_client-5.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (83kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 522kB/s
Collecting bleach (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading bleach-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting mistune!=0.6 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading mistune-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pandocfilters>=1.4.1 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading pandocfilters-1.4.1.tar.gz
Collecting testpath (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading testpath-0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 92kB 1.3MB/s
Collecting entrypoints>=0.2.2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading entrypoints-0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jinja2 (from nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading Jinja2-2.9.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (340kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 348kB 1.5MB/s
Collecting tornado>=4.0 (from ipykernel->jupyter)
  Downloading tornado-4.4.2.tar.gz (460kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 460kB 982kB/s
Collecting prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0 (from jupyter-console->jupyter)
  Downloading prompt_toolkit-1.0.13-py3-none-any.whl (247kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 1.3MB/s
Collecting ipython-genutils (from notebook->jupyter)
  Downloading ipython_genutils-0.2.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jsonschema!=2.5.0,>=2.4 (from nbformat>=4.2.0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading jsonschema-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting six (from traitlets>=4.3.1->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading six-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting decorator (from traitlets>=4.3.1->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading decorator-4.0.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=18.5 in c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\
programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->
jupyter)
Collecting colorama; sys_platform == "win32" (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->j
upyter)
  Downloading colorama-0.3.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pickleshare (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading pickleshare-0.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting simplegeneric>0.8 (from ipython>=4.0.0->ipywidgets->jupyter)
  Downloading simplegeneric-0.8.1.zip
Collecting pyzmq>=13 (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)
  Downloading pyzmq-16.0.2-cp36-cp36m-win32.whl (790kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 798kB 147kB/s
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.1 (from jupyter-client>=4.1->qtconsole->jupyter)
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (194kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 194kB 1.7MB/s
Collecting html5lib>=0.99999999 (from bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading html5lib-0.999999999-py2.py3-none-any.whl (112kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 122kB 1.6MB/s
Collecting MarkupSafe>=0.23 (from jinja2->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading MarkupSafe-1.0.tar.gz
Collecting wcwidth (from prompt-toolkit<2.0.0,>=1.0.0->jupyter-console->jupyter)

  Downloading wcwidth-0.1.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting webencodings (from html5lib>=0.99999999->bleach->nbconvert->jupyter)
  Downloading webencodings-0.5.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: tornado, pyzmq, six, ipython-genutils, decorator,
 traitlets, jupyter-core, python-dateutil, jupyter-client, colorama, pickleshare
, simplegeneric, wcwidth, prompt-toolkit, pygments, ipython, ipykernel, jsonsche
ma, nbformat, webencodings, html5lib, bleach, mistune, pandocfilters, testpath,
entrypoints, MarkupSafe, jinja2, nbconvert, notebook, widgetsnbextension, ipywid
gets, qtconsole, jupyter-console, jupyter
  Running setup.py install for tornado ... error
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
    return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 22: invalid
 continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\req\req_install.py", line 878, in install
    spinner=spinner,
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 676, in call_subprocess
    line = console_to_str(proc.stdout.readline())
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 75, in console_to_str
    return s.decode('utf_8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 22: invalid
 continuation byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\commands\install.py", line 385, in run
    requirement_set.cleanup_files()
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\req\req_set.py", line 729, in cleanup_files
    req.remove_temporary_source()
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\req\req_install.py", line 977, in remove_temporary_source
    rmtree(self.source_dir)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 393, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.rmdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] El proceso no tiene acceso al archivo porque está
 siendo utilizado por otro proceso: 'C:\\Users\\MYUSER\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pi
p-build-fives7dn\\tornado'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\commands\install.py", line 385, in run
    requirement_set.cleanup_files()
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\utils\build.py", line 38, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\utils\build.py", line 42, in cleanup
    rmtree(self.name)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 686, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 494, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 384, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\shutil.py",
 line 389, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "c:\users\myuser\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packag
es\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 114, in rmtree_errorhandler
    func(path)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Acceso denegado: 'C:\\Users\\MYUSER\\AppData\\Loca
l\\Temp\\pip-build-fives7dn\\testpath\\testpath\\cli-32.exe'
```

It might be that my username contains an "à" in the name? If so it is the problem, what can I do?

Comment: I no longer use this OS so I can't tell people if your proposed solutions work. Nonetheless I hope people with this problem can appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually just because of your "à" in your username. Here is the error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 22: invalid continuation byte
```

You just need to remove some character in your username that does not follow the standard utf-8 characters, for example, change "à" to "a".

Answer (score 0):

**I** met the same problem as yours. I updated my Python to version 3.6.1 and re-install Jupyter notebook. I encounter the first problem **UnicodeDecodeError** when pip setting up **tornado**, my system is Windows 8.1 64bit.
Here is what I do to solve it:

- I open the directory **...\Python\Python36\Lib\site-packages\tornado** where new python installed
- open the directory **...\Python\Python35\Lib\site-packages\tornado** where old python installed
- Then I copy and overwrite all ***.py** files in new tornado directory form old tornado (Note: my old tornado is the latest 4.4.2)
- Then I run instruction **pip install jupyter notebook** again

then the same problem when pip setting up **MarkupSafe**, I do same as above. This time instruction **pip install jupyter notebook** do not throw error anymore.And Jupyter notebook works.

**I** think if you have the old version modules of Jupyter, you can try as what I do, Or think about download the error module manually and place them into right directory.

Hope this can help you.